# Data doesn't show in recyclerView, need to go back to show it

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to create an activity to search for users by full name. I created everything I needed and it worked properly, except for one thing. When I press search button the result are not show in recyclerview. I need to go back and the the results are shown. I need to do these 2 steps to see the results.

[image]

[image]

Yes the search bar and view holder are overlap, I will try to fixed later. Do you know how to make it so that once searched the results are displayed immediately without having to go back

This is my layout for view holder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    android:background="@drawable/recycler_view_border">

    <com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageProfile"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:tint="#808080"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/dark_blue"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/defaultimage"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userFullName"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageProfile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/fullname"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"/>

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="340dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
        app:cornerRadius="8dp"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is my layout for activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SendFriendRequests">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/searchUsername"
            android:layout_width="318dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edt_background"
            android:hint="@string/searchFriends"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:importantForAutofill="no"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp" />


        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/buttonSearch"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="333dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-47dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_background"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            app:cornerRadius="8dp" />


    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="580dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearlayout"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.99"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-16dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my adapter

```
package com.example.chatappjava;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SendFriendRequestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SendFriendRequestAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = "ContactsAdapter";

    private ArrayList<UserData> arrayListUserData = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public SendFriendRequestAdapter(ArrayList<UserData> arrayListUserData, Context context) {
        this.arrayListUserData = arrayListUserData;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_send_friend_request_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        Glide.with(context)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(arrayListUserData.get(position).image)
                .into(holder.userProfileImage);

        holder.userFullName.setText(arrayListUserData.get(position).name);

        holder.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.createDatabaseConnection();

                    PreparedStatement st1 = conn.prepareStatement(
                            " insert into FRIEND_REQUESTS values (?,?,?)");
                    st1.setString(1, arrayListUserData.get(position).friendId);
                    st1.setString(2, arrayListUserData.get(position).userId);
                    st1.setInt(3, 0);
                    st1.execute();

                    showToast("Friend request is sended");

                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("IdAccount", arrayListUserData.get(position).userId);
                    context.startActivity(intent);

                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), specificchat.class);
                intent.putExtra("userId", arrayListUserData.get(position).userId);
                intent.putExtra("friendId", arrayListUserData.get(position).friendId);
                intent.putExtra("friendName", arrayListUserData.get(position).name);
                intent.putExtra("friendImage", arrayListUserData.get(position).image);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayListUserData.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircularImageView userProfileImage;
        TextView userFullName;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;
        Button buttonAdd;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            userProfileImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageProfile);
            userFullName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.userFullName);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
            buttonAdd = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my java class which use the adapter

```
package com.example.chatappjava;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SendFriendRequests extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<UserData> arrayListUserData = new ArrayList<>();
    private Button searchButton;
    private EditText searchUsername;
    private String userId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        userId = intent.getStringExtra("IdAccount");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_send_friend_request);
        searchButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        searchUsername = findViewById(R.id.searchUsername);

        searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.createDatabaseConnection();
                    Statement statement = conn.createStatement();

                    ResultSet resultat = statement.executeQuery("select ID, FULLNAME, IMAGE from USERS where ID not in (select FRIEND_ID from FRIENDSLIST where USER_ID = " + userId  + ") and FULLNAME like '%" + searchUsername.getText().toString() + "%' and ID not in (select RECEIVER_ID from FRIEND_REQUESTS where SENDER_ID = " + userId  + ")");
                    while (resultat.next()) {
                        arrayListUserData.add(new UserData(resultat.getString("FULLNAME"), resultat.getString("IMAGE"), resultat.getString("ID"), userId));
                    }
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                initRecycleView();

            }
        });


    }

    private void initRecycleView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        SendFriendRequestAdapter adapter = new SendFriendRequestAdapter(arrayListUserData, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's the `RecyclerView` in your XML that needs to be adjusted at `android:layout_height = "0dp"`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearlayout"/>
```